# Error in JSF is not clear

Tags: jsf

I'm doing demo fileupload using Tomahawk from http://balusc.blogspot.com. It's ok but in a portion in my code fired error, this code in last time ran normally. This is log file:

> StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception com.sun.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "." at line 2, column 37. Was expecting: `<IDENTIFIER>` ... at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.generateParseException(ELParser.java:2309) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.jj_consume_token(ELParser.java:2191) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.DotSuffix(ELParser.java:1094) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.ValueSuffix(ELParser.java:1071) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.Value(ELParser.java:1016) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.Unary(ELParser.java:986) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.Multiplication(ELParser.java:750) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.Math(ELParser.java:670) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.Compare(ELParser.java:482) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.Equality(ELParser.java:376) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.And(ELParser.java:320) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.Or(ELParser.java:264) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.Choice(ELParser.java:222) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.Expression(ELParser.java:214) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.DeferredExpression(ELParser.java:152) at com.sun.el.parser.ELParser.CompositeExpression(ELParser.java:80) at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:177) at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:229) at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:273) at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:98) at com.sun.jsftemplating.component.ComponentUtil.resolveValue(ComponentUtil.java:608) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.getInputValue(Handler.java:197) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.HandlerContextImpl.getInputValue(HandlerContextImpl.java:142) at com.sun.jsftemplating.handlers.UtilHandlers.write(UtilHandlers.java:160) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encode(LayoutElementBase.java:321) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutDefinition.encode(LayoutDefinition.java:250) at com.sun.jsftemplating.renderer.TemplateRenderer.encodeEnd(TemplateRenderer.java:139) at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.RenderingUtilities.renderComponent(RenderingUtilities.java:99) at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.TableColumnRenderer.encodeChildren(TableColumnRenderer.java:188) at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.RenderingUtilities.renderComponent(RenderingUtilities.java:91) at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.TableRowGroupRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRowGroupRenderer.java:199) at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.RenderingUtilities.renderComponent(RenderingUtilities.java:91) at com.sun.webui.jsf.renderkit.html.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:168) at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:551) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:555) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:555) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:555) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encodeChild(LayoutElementBase.java:555) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.encode(LayoutComponent.java:243) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.encode(LayoutElementBase.java:348) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutDefinition.encode(LayoutDefinition.java:246) at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.renderView(LayoutViewHandler.java:683) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: At the very least, you could provide a link to the actual page with the code.

Comment: And specify your configuration

Comment: Post the JSF code that's giving you problems. Community won't guess what problem you have at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Verify that you have included in the "WEB-INF/lib" the libraries "el-api-2.2.jar" and "el-impl-2.2.jar".

Regards,